# Keeping string rows only if the begging of any string dont appear more than once in the data set for certain values

Tags: python, string, pandas

Here an example of what I have in Pandas:

```
    Name                        id    country
    Infinity War (extras)       null  ES
    Infinity War                18236 ES
    Infinity War (extras)       null  IT
    Batman V Superman (extras)  32512 UK
    Jurassic World              52130 FR
    Blade Runner (extra)        null  FR
    Blade Runner                5390  FR
```

I would like to delete Infinity War (extras) ES and Blade Runner (extra), since the title of the movie itself appears also for that country. I have find in functions like isin,starswith,findall,contains... but all of them needs specifying the string you are looking for, and I need to take out all of them without specifying.

EDIT: I have found another limitation that I did not know. I have also the titles:

```
Ghostbusters (1984)
Ghostbusters (2016)
```

For that case, @Zero and @zipa answers dont work because they will keep just one movie instead of both. For making @jpp solution works, I have modified it for adding '(extra)' option (which I did not include initially in the question):

```
m1 = df['Name'].str.endswith(' (extras)',' (extra)')
```

Applying jpp's code for each country individually solved my problem.

Comment: Try `df[~df.a.str.split(' \(').str[0].duplicated(keep='last')]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a combination of `str.endswith` and index-based slicing. The below solution will delete *all* occurrences of `'SomeMovieName (extras)'` where `'SomeMovieName'` exists.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Name': ['Infinity War (extras)', 'Infinity War',
                            'Batman V Superman (extras)', 'Jurassic World'],
                   'ID': [np.nan, 18236, 32512, 52130]})

names = df['Name'].unique()

m1 = df['Name'].str.endswith(' (extras)')
m2 = df['Name'].str[:-9].isin(names)

res = df[~(m1 & m2)]
```

**Result**

```
        ID                        Name
1  18236.0                Infinity War
2  32512.0  Batman V Superman (extras)
3  52130.0              Jurassic World
```

Comment: Is there any way to take in account films ended with "(extra)" and "(extras)"? I have tried with m1 = df['Name'].str.endswith(' (extras)',' (extra)') but it does not work. Thank you

Comment: Sure, use `tuple`: i.e. `df['Name'].str.endswith((' (extras)', ' (extra)'))`.

Answer (score 1):

This will keep only the shortest versions, based on beginning:

```
df[df['A'].apply(lambda x: sum(1 for i in df['A'] if x.startswith(i)))==1]
#                            A      B
#1                Infinity War  18236
#2  Batman V Superman (extras)  32512
#3              Jurassic World  52130
```

Comment: Doesn't this have O(n^2) time complexity? You are iterating all of `df['A']` for every row? I don't think anything more than O(*n*) is necessary.

Comment: @jpp It does, but again, it performs a different operation then the one you suggested. If there are better approaches to solve my approach I'm open to learning :)

Comment: Yeh, I'm not sure I can improve on your logic (without changing it to something like my answer). It seems the *result* should be the same.